# Do all ethernet frames contain an LLC header?

Tags: networking, ethernet

As the title states: do all ethernet frames contain an LLC header? In other words, is 802.2 mandatory?

When doing pcap using wireshark, the LLC filter shows no results.

If LLC is not mandatory, then when is it used, and what indicates whether that header is in the frame.

Note that http://www.ieee802.org/2/ states that 802.2 has been disbanded.

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [NetworkEngineering.SE]

Answer (score 3):

Why should IEEE 802.2 be mandatory? There other Ethernet frame types exist (e.g. DIX Ethernet, IEEE 802.3.) 
As it can be seen by the picture below IEEE 802.3 frame has LLC header while Ethernet DIX frame doesn't include LLC header in its structure.

[image: Ethernet II (DIX Ethernet) frame and IEEE 802.3 frame]